# T-invariant subspace has a T-invariant complement implies minimal polynomial has nice form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$ and let $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ be a linear operator on $V$. Let $U$ be a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$, and let $T|_U$ be the restriction of $T$ to $U$. Denote passage into the quotient by $U$ of $T$ by $\overline{T}$.

Now assume that $U$ has a $T$-invariant direct complement (i.e., $\exists W\le V$ with $W$ $T$-invariant and $V = U \oplus W$). Let $m(t)$, $m_1(t)$, and $m_2(t)$ be the minimal polynomials for $T$, $T|_U$, and $\overline{T}$ respectively. I am asked to prove that $m(t) = \operatorname{lcm}\{m_1(t),m_2(t)\}$.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Consider the division algorithm of $m_1$ and $m$, i.e. let $p, r \in K[x]$ be the unique polynomials such that $m = pm_1+r$ with $\deg(r) < \deg(m_1)$. Then $r = m-pm_1$ and $r(T|_U) = m(T|_U) -p(T|_U)m_1(T|_U) = 0 - 0 = 0$, contradicting the minimality of degree of $m_1$, so that $r = 0$ and $m_1 | m$. Similarly, $m_2 | m$ so that $\operatorname{lcm}\{m_1,m_2\} | m$

I'm not quite sure how to proceed. As of yet I haven't used the invariant complement condition, and I realize intuitively it's that $\overline{T}$ is the same as $T|_W$ so that $T = T|_U + T|_W$ but I can't quite get it to work. I've seen an approach that uses matrices but I'd rather stick with operators if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In establishing that $m_2 \mid m$, you have indeed used the invariant complement condition, since if $W$ were a complement that was not $T$ invariant, it could be that $p(\overline{T})$ annihilates $V/U$ although $p(T)$ does not annihilate $W$ (so long as $p(T)$ sends $V$ into $U$).

The part of the proof you are still working on is actually the easy part: if $m_1, m_2 \mid p$, then $p$ annihilates $V$.

---

If you have learned some ring theory: in general, if $R$ is a principal ideal domain, and $M, N$ are $R$ modules where $(r_1) = \text{Ann}_R(M)$, and $(r_2) = \text{Ann}_R(N)$, then $\text{Ann}_R(M \oplus N) = \text{Ann}_R(M) \cap \text{Ann}_R(N) = \text{lcm}(r_1, r_2)$.