# Is the minimal polynomial of $T$ equal to the product of these Restrictions?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a finite dimensional Vector Space over $F$
Let $Y$ be a $T$-invariant subspace $Y \neq 0$ $Y \neq V$

I have these facts as well

$V = Y \oplus Y'$ where $Y' \simeq V/Y$

I also know that the minimal polynomials of $T|_{Y}$ and $T|_{V/Y}$ divide the minimal polynomial of $T$

I am  just having trouble figuring out if I were to multiply those minimal polynomials, would it equal the minimal polynomial of $T$?

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. In fact, generally a $T$-invariant subspace might not have a $T$-invariant complement. However if both $Y$ and $Y'$ are $T$-invariant, then the minimal polynomial will be the least common multiple of the minimal polynomials of $T|_Y$ and ${T|_{Y'}}_.$

Here is a link to a similar question: [T-invariant subspace has a T-invariant complement implies minimal polynomial has nice form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364550/t-invariant-subspace-has-a-t-invariant-complement-implies-minimal-polynomial-has).